# MySQL Import cannot find function

Tags: mysql

I am very confused about this. is there something wrong?

[image]

the function is already in the sql :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ev_total_hari`;
delimiter ;;
CREATE FUNCTION `ev_total_hari`(`id_event` INT)
 RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result INT;
    SELECT to_days(tanggal_selesai) - to_days(tanggal_mulai) + 1 INTO result FROM `event` WHERE id=id_event LIMIT 1;
    RETURN result;
END
;;
delimiter ;
```

Thanks, hope u can help me!

Comment: and are you sure youre creating the function in the right database?

Comment: yeah, iam very sure

Comment: Check does your account have [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) privilege. Also check that the function is created before problematic query execution.

Comment: Double-check that you created the function and in which schema: `select routine_schema, routine_name from information_schema.routines where routine_name = 'ev_total_hari';`